# Nested choice in RelaxNG

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xml-validation, relaxng

I would like to do a nested choice with group elements in relaxNG. Since relaxNG doesn't support conditional statements, I have to group together elements for value of True vs False). I can't use compact relaxNG since lxml(python library) doesn't support it and the elements won't be in order and I need interleave for that. What I am trying to achieve is like this.

```
if A is True: 
    do nothing.
else:
    if B is True: 
       do nothing
    else: 
       2 more elements appear
    if C is True: 
       do nothing
    else: 
       2 more elements appear
```

I am currently using choice with group to group together elements. As you can see the B and C are nested inside A. When I use

```
<choice>
    A - True
    <group>
        <interleave> 
        A - False
        <choice> 
           B - True
           <group>
               <interleave> 
               B - False, two elements appear
               <interleave> 
           </group>
        </choice>
        <choice>
           C - True
           <group>
               <interleave> 
               C - False, two elements appear
               <interleave> 
           </group>
         </choice>
         </interleave>
    </group>
</choice>
```

Currently, the code is giving me errors saying Element has extra content. I believe that is the interleave problem. But I don't know how to achieve the result.

Comment: It’s hard to evaluate without having a real schema to test with rather than the `A - True` etc. stuff in your snippet. Also the snippet isn’t well-formed—it has ` <interleave>` start tags in two places where it should have `</interleave>` end tags. Also if lxml uses libxml2 for RelaxNG checking, you may just be running into a bug in libxml2, because it’s known to have some serious bugs in its RelaxNG support. So you may want to try also testing with jing to see if you get the same error.

Comment: As @sideshowbarker stated, libxml2 is indeed flawed. Then, lxml, which uses libxml2, does not work properly. When I tested the xml with Jing, it shows no error but with lxml, the above syntax is giving errors. Takeaway from this, use Jing for validating RelaxNG or pyjing, python wrapper for Jing.